# How to fix "Could not retrieve mirrorlist" error in vagrant?

Tags: vagrant, yum

When ever I run vagrant up, I am getting the following error.

```
==> default: [2019-05-30T13:09:31+00:00] INFO: Running queued delayed notifications before re-raising exception
==> default:
==> default: ================================================================================
==> default: Error executing action `create` on resource 'yum_repository[ius]'
==> default: ================================================================================
==> default:
==> default:
==> default: Mixlib::ShellOut::ShellCommandFailed
==> default: ------------------------------------
==> default: execute[yum-makecache-ius] (/tmp/vagrant-chef/bb6e5277837de973166d09e85978af4a/cookbooks/yum/providers/repository.rb line 55) had an error: Mixlib::ShellOut::ShellCommandFailed: Expected process to exit with [0], but received '1'
==> default: ---- Begin output of yum -q makecache --disablerepo=* --enablerepo=ius ----
==> default: STDOUT: Could not retrieve mirrorlist http://mirrors.iuscommunity.org/mirrorlist/?repo=ius-el6&arch=x86_64&protocol=https error was
==> default: 14: problem making ssl connection
==> default: STDERR: Error: Cannot find a valid baseurl for repo: ius
==> default: ---- End output of yum -q makecache --disablerepo=* --enablerepo=ius ----
==> default: Ran yum -q makecache --disablerepo=* --enablerepo=ius returned 1
==> default:
```

Seems like something wrong with this URL:
http://mirrors.iuscommunity.org/mirrorlist/?repo=ius-el6&arch=x86_64&protocol=https

I tried with https and http. Even tried disabling sslverify false.

Can someone please help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

You’re probably running into some SSL certificate and TLS problems. Type on terminal :

```
yum -y install ca-certificates openssl nss
```

Than retry again